# Fazer leitor de tela ler texto do alt de imagem

Tags: acessibilidade

Olá minha questão é sobre acessibilidade: estou fazendo a acessibilidade de uma página e nela tenho uma imagem com um link, estou usando o leitor de tela jaws para percorrer todos elementos definidos.

Um desses elementos é essa imagem com link, preciso que quando chegar nesse elemento (usando TAB) o leitor de tela leia o ALT dessa imagem.

```
<a href="javascript:;" class=""><img src="imagem-qualquer.jpg" width="54" height="54" alt="Descurtir" title="Descurtir">
 </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Jose vc está usando o **`aria-hidden`** como **`true`**, nesse caso o leitor de tela vai ignorar o seu elemento! Retire o aria-hidden que o Alt deve voltar a funcionar.

> User agents determine an element's hidden status based on whether it
>   is rendered, and the rendering is usually controlled by CSS. For
>   example, an element whose display property is set to none is not
>   rendered. An element is considered hidden if it, or any of its
>   ancestors are not rendered or have their aria-hidden attribute value
>   set to true.

**FONTE:** https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden

Aqui tem um check list de  da WebAim que é bem legal pra vc entender como o leitor de tela interpreta a imagem e seus atributos
https://webaim.org/articles/nvda/images.htm

Outra coisa, considere usar a tag  ela é mais semântica e tem mais atributos. Veja o exemplo. (vc não precisa usar o figcaption, ou pode usar css para tira-lo da tela, mas deixar visível para o leitor de tela)

```
<figure aria-labelledby="nome-da-img" role="img">
    <img src="nome-da-imagem.jpg" alt="Descrição completa da imagem">
    <figcaption id="nome-da-img">Descrição da imagem</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre o Role, Type e Alt:
https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/HTML/wiki/RoleAttribute

Comment: Hugocsl, não esta com aria-hidden, já usei o aria-labelledby, mas não surtiu efeito, essa tela é toda montado por um .js, talvez por isso tenha algo impedindo, agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: @josecarlos na citação que eu postei fala assim: " An element is considered hidden if it, or any of its ancestors are not rendered or have their aria-hidden" Isso quer dizer que se o PAI do elemento tiver `aria-hidden="true" o filho vai ser ignorado pelo leitor de tela` e no seu código a imagem está dentro de um link com `aria-hidden="true"` `<a href="javascript:;" class="" aria-hidden="true"> <img> </a>`

Comment: hugocsl, sim vdd, mas foi um teste que fiz, com e sem o aria-hidden, mas não surtiu efeito esperado, o leitor informa como grafico e colocando o aria-hidden="true" e ele ignora essa informação. Valeu.

Comment: Jose tire o aria-hidden="true" do Link depois coloque tabindex="0" na <img> Tipo assim `<a tabindex="0" href="javascript:;" class="" role="link" aria-label="Descurtir"><img tabindex="0" src="imagem-qualquer.jpg" width="54" height="54" alt="Descurtir" aria-labelledby="Descurtir"></a>` se assim não der certo é pq tem outro coisa impedindo que o Jaws faça a leitura. Ai te aconselho a tentar com outro leitor de tela.

Comment: Hugocsl, já testei sem o aria-hidden="true", não surtiu efeito, é outra coisa que esta impedindo, fiz teste com o NVDA tmb e funciona.